# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'OR'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

In My code i want to search all fields in just one textbox but i got this error:

`An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'OR'.`

```
cn.Open()

With cmd
    .Connection = cn
    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FactandStaff WHERE Familyname OR Firstname like '%" & txtsearch.Text & "%'"
End With

da.SelectCommand = cmd

dt.Clear()
da.Fill(dt)

dg2.DataSource = dt

cn.Close()
```

Comment: You can't say `col1 or col2 =/LIKE something` - you need to change it to `WHERE FamilyName LIKE '%something%' OR FirstName LIKE '%something%'`. Also you really, really, really need to read up on SQL injection and parameterized queries. This code is begging to be the next news story about a database getting exploited through its web site...

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand-Tnx sir it worked well. I'm looking forward on reading much more about SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CommandText` should be:

```
SELECT * FROM FactandStaff WHERE Familyname LIKE '%" & txtsearch.Text & "%' OR Firstname LIKE '%" & txtsearch.Text & "%'
```

So it becomes:

```
With cmd
    .Connection = cn
    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FactandStaff WHERE Familyname LIKE '%" & txtsearch.Text & "%' OR Firstname LIKE '%" & txtsearch.Text & "%'"
End With
```